# Best way to create a menu that scrolls up from the bottom?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, menu, subview

I'm fairly new to iPhone programming, and I'm making a fairly basic app. Anyway, I just want to know how to go about creating a menu that scrolls up from the bottom (beginning at the top of the tab bar) that displays a few options. I've attached a picture that better helps portray what I mean. I'm assuming I should create some sort of subview and then add some animation to it, but I'd like to get your advice on the best way to start.
Thanks

[image: Home Screen]
[image: Menu]

Comment: I find your interface really attractive to the eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use a UIActionSheet, unmodified.

If that's not what you're looking for, using a modal view controller is always an option.

If, however, you want something that won't cover the entire screen, and can have a custom look, the basic idea is this:

1. Create your view with a frame that's just at the bottom of your main view (e.g. at 0,406).
2. Optionally disable user interaction with the main view
3. Use UIView animations to move it up

The code would look something like this:

```
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, kCustomViewHeight)];
[self.view addSubview:customView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
  CGRect f = customView.frame;
  f.origin.y -= kCustomViewHeight;
  customView.frame = f;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do it myself, but saw a cool source-code, where it was performed with the helped of UIScrollView (by default positioned "below" the screen), containing UITableView and a button (wich was shown at the bottom of the screen). ScrollView was getting a command to move after the press of this button (in IBAction of it).
Being shorter, try to look at UIScrollView (play with UITableView in it).

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, popping up some object from the bottom of the screen by subclassing UIActionSheet and adding my own controls as subviews. I imagine a similar method could be used in your situation.

Create a subclass of UIActionSheet implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols. In the `- (id)init` method of that class, add a `UITableView` as a subview with `self` as the delegate and data source.

Then from the main view, call your custom UIActionSheet with `showInView:`.

Use delegates to call back to the main view to let it know when the user selects an option, then use `[myCustomMenu dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]` to hide the menu.